# How to get weighted sample data in Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, hive

I know we can do some random sample in hive using something like `Row_Number() OVER (partition by deptid ORDER BY rand() desc)` (assuming we want to get some row data randomly in some partitions.

However, I don't know how to get some rows based on one column value. For example we want to get some data weighted by salary. How to do that?

Data like

```
create table employee (empid int ,deptid int ,salary decimal(10,2))
insert into employee values(1,10,5500.00)
insert into employee values(2,10,4500.00)
insert into employee values(3,20,1900.00)
insert into employee values(4,20,4800.00)
insert into employee values(5,40,6500.00)
insert into employee values(6,40,14500.00)
insert into employee values(7,40,44500.00)
insert into employee values(8,50,6500.00)
insert into employee values(9,50,7500.00)
```

Is there a way to do it in HIVE?

Comment: Please add expected result as well.

Comment: Hi @Raid, I think the result can be different as it's weighted sampled. I think the goal is that if an employee has higher salary, then they have more chance to show in the final sampled data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple idea to pick sample records based on a partition of salaries.
You can use -

1. partition by buckets of salaries. You can bucket them using cast(salary/10000 as INT). You can change 10000 to any number to create buckets of your choosing. If you choose 10000, per your example, 4500,5500,1900 etc will go to partition 1, 14500 will go to partition 2, 44500 will go to partition 3 etc.
2. `order by rand()` - this will give you random order in above partition.

SQL -

```
select * from (
select e.* ,
row_number() over(partition by cast(salary/10000 as INT) order by rand()) rn
from employee e)rs where rn <3 -- choose 2 records per partition
```

Now, my thought on weighted sampling can be something simple as pick sample records based on a partition or can be as complex as pick sample records based on how large the salary is. For second scenario, you need to tweak the order by.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Koushik! This is what I did for now, however it's still introducing the bucket, so it's not identical to the real weighted sampling. But I think it's fine to go with bucket sampling for now. Thanks.

Comment: So, what you are expecting for weighted sampling? can you give some example from your sample data.

Comment: let's say we have input data like 

user  salary 
1        100
2        200
3        300
4        400

then I want a weighted sample with 2 people, the probability of a user in the final sample is based on the probability of their salary weight. For example, the probability of user4 been selected is 400/(100+200+300+400), and for user1 the probability is 100/(1000). 
I know the dataframe has the function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas-dataframe-sample